# JUnit Jupiter yellow line on exception test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I have a function that creates a user.

```
@Override
public User createUser(UserDTO userDTO) throws UserNameExistException {
    boolean isUserNameExists = userRepo.existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName());
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    User user = modelMapper.map(userDTO,User.class);

    if (isUserNameExists) {
        throw new UserNameExistException(user.getUserName());
    }
    user = userRepo.save(user);
    userKafkaProducer.sendMessage(user);
    return user;
    
}
```

To test this, I wrote two test functions. For success case

```
     @Test
    public void testCreateUserSuccess() throws UserNameExistException {
        // Arrange
        UserRepository userRepo = mock(UserRepository.class);
        UserKafkaProducer userKafkaProducer = mock(UserKafkaProducer.class);
        UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepo, userKafkaProducer);

        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setUserName("test_user");

        when(userRepo.existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName())).thenReturn(false);

        User savedUser = new User();
        savedUser.setUserName("test_user");
        savedUser.setId("1");
        when(userRepo.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(savedUser);

        User user = userService.createUser(userDTO);

        assertNotNull(user);
        assertNotNull(user.getId());
        assertEquals(userDTO.getUserName(), user.getUserName());
        verify(userRepo, times(1)).existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName());
        verify(userRepo, times(1)).save(any(User.class));
        verify(userKafkaProducer, times(1)).sendMessage(user); //mock ?

    }
```

And for exception case

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateUserUserNameExists() throws UserNameExistException {

        UserRepository userRepo = mock(UserRepository.class);
        UserKafkaProducer userKafkaProducer = mock(UserKafkaProducer.class);
        UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(userRepo, userKafkaProducer);

        UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();
        userDTO.setUserName("existing_user");

        when(userRepo.existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName())).thenReturn(true);

        assertThrows(UserNameExistException.class, () -> userService.createUser(userDTO));
        verify(userRepo, times(1)).existsByUserName(userDTO.getUserName());
        verify(userRepo, times(0)).save(any(User.class));
        verify(userKafkaProducer, times(0)).sendMessage(any(User.class));
    }
```

When I check the operation under test I see it has 100% coverage, every row is green.

In the test class, every line is green in the successful function.
But in the exception function, the line below is yellow.

```
assertThrows(UserNameExistException.class, () -> userService.createUser(userDTO));
```

What other possibility should I test for this line to be green in the test as well?

Comment: You dont have to have 100% line coverage on TESTS! So if the line itself is "yellow", then this doesnt mean anything, because tests should be EXCLUDED from code coverage, or else you have to write tests for tests, and then even tests for these tests

Comment: Yes, @Loading is right. Test coverage is calculated for your code, which is covered in test cases. You do not need to coverage your test code.

Comment: It made a lot of sense when I thought about it that way. The main idea is about the logic of writing tests. Thanks. Is there a reason why test classes are also included in the measurement when we run it by saying coverage as JUnit Test on Eclipse?

Comment: it could be an automatic thing or a misconfiguration by your ide/repo, but sonarqube for example excludes them by default. You should look into filters and setup your coverage correctly